# How iterate over all the values in an array in Django

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, django-templates

I have an array of names in python, which I would like to display using Django templates. I know that tags can be used that support for loops, but they have a unique syntax which I am unfamiliar with.

Also I do not want to use instance.0, instance.1 and so on. I need to be scalable for any size array

Django Template code

```
(:,

{% for name  in instance  %}
       {{instance}}         
{%endfor%}

 My name is {{my_name}}.
(:,
```

Python code

```
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()


t=Template(The above section)
dtype={'names': ['name','offset'],
       'formats':['U20,U20']
       }

instance = np.zeros(5,dtype='U20')
instance[0]=('John')
instance[1]=('Tim')
instance[2]=('Sarah')

name="adrian"


c=Context({"instance":instance, "my_name":name})
print(t.render(c))
```

Current output

(:,

```
                [&#39;John&#39; &#39;Tim&#39; &#39;Sarah&#39; &#39;&#39; &#39;&#39;]


                [&#39;John&#39; &#39;Tim&#39; &#39;Sarah&#39; &#39;&#39; &#39;&#39;]


                [&#39;John&#39; &#39;Tim&#39; &#39;Sarah&#39; &#39;&#39; &#39;&#39;]


                [&#39;John&#39; &#39;Tim&#39; &#39;Sarah&#39; &#39;&#39; &#39;&#39;]


                [&#39;John&#39; &#39;Tim&#39; &#39;Sarah&#39; &#39;&#39; &#39;&#39;]


       My name is adrian.
       ).
```

Desired output

```
(:,
        i=0

               [John]


               [Tim]


               [Sarah]




       My name is adrian.
       ).
```

Comment: instead of `{{instance}}`, output `{{name}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting the queryset/iterable, i.e. `instance`.

Instead, you need to output each element of it, which is `name`, as you correctly state in the `for` loop.

The syntax of the `for` is the same as python's (see if [this helps](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop))

so just replace

```
{{instance}}
```

with

```
{{name}}
```

in the template and you should get the desired output

That means the template should be

```
(:,

{% for name  in instance  %}
       {{name}}
{% endfor %}

 My name is {{my_name}}.
(:,
```

By the way, I can see the queryset has five elements (the same line was repeated five times because the loop ran on five elements), but the last two lack a name since only John, Tim and Sarah appear.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have a new use case. How can I have  a for loop print out values from 2 different arrays? Like { for name in instance}      {{name}} {{Last_name}}

Comment: to iterate over two different sequences pairing the elements form each, you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). e.g. `{% for name, last_name in zip(arr1, arr2) %}` `{{ name }}` `{{ last_name }}` `{% endfor %}`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to access zip from within the for loop.All computations have to be done outside the template. Also I think this is my question asked in a better way.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286510/displaying-2-values-in-a-record-array-using-django-template-for-loop

Comment: Ok, but then how do I use the Context() method with the combined arrays?

Comment: I am looking at your new question. Maybe you there is no need to change much. See my comment there