# Displaying 2 values in a record array using Django template for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, django-templates

I have a numpy record array with 2 values per slot in the array.The name and offset, I want to display both of these values side by side using a Django template.

Python code

```
import numpy as np
from django.template import Template, Context, loader
from django.conf import settings

dtype={
    'names' : ('name','offset'),
    'formats' : ('U20','U20')}

instance= np.zeros(3,dtype)


instance[0]=('xga_control_reg','008')
instance[1]=('i_cmd_REG','012')
instance[2]=('i_ee_cmd_reg','016')

t=Template(The Django Template below)
c=Context({"instance":instance['name'],"instance":instance['offset']})
print(t.render(c))
```

Django Template

```
--
--   generated with parser version 1.09
--
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package regfile
          (
            {% for name  in instance%}
                   Name is  {{name}}  "{{name}}" 
            {%endfor%}

           ).""")
```

Current output

```
--
--   generated with parser version 1.09
--
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


package regfile
          (

               Name is  008  "008" 

               Name is  012  "012" 

               Name is  016  "016" 


          ).
```

Desired Output

```
--
--   generated with parser version 1.09
--
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


package regfile
      (

               Name is  xga_control_reg  "008" 

               Name is  i_cmd_REG  "012" 

               Name is  i_ee_cmd_reg  "016" 

       ).
```

I need to be able to display 2 values on the same line using the tag for loop in a Django template. If this can be done with 2 separate arrays instead of a numpy record array, that would be acceptable. Thank you!

Comment: I have never used numpy. What is the type of `instance[0]`? do `print(type(instance[0]))`

Comment: Numpy is just the module for using record arrays. In a record array you can define how many variables you want per index. The important part is the desired output and how to get there. Here is a link for numpy arrays http://people.rit.edu/blbgse/pythonNotes/numpy.html. Printing instance[0]= xga_control 008

Comment: ok. how do you access each variable? `instance[0].name`? `instance[0]['name']`? From the link you provided I would think the latter

Comment: in the template try using the dot notation `{% for el in instance %}` `Name is  {{el.name}}  "{{el.offset}}"` `{% endfor %}`